# Testify mock is returning assertion that the function has not been called

Tags: go, mocking, testify

My tests keep failing with but `no actual calls happened` but I am positive the func is getting called (It's a logging function so I see the logs on the terminal)

Basically I have code that looks something like this :

`common/utils.go`

---

```
func LogNilValue(ctx string){
    log.Logger.Warn(ctx)
}
```

`main.go`

---

```
import (
"common/utils"
)

func CheckFunc(*string value) {
    ctx := "Some context string"
    if value == nil {
    utils.LogNilValue(ctx) //void func that just logs the string
   }
}
```

`test.go`

---

```
type MyMockedObject struct{
    mock.Mock
}

func TestNil() {
    m := new(MyMockedObject)
    m.Mock.On("LogNilValue", mock.Anything).Return(nil)
    CheckFunc(nil)
    m.AssertCalled(s.T(), "LogNilValue", mock.Anything)
}
```

I expect this to work but then, I keep getting `no actual calls happened`. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Which logging library you are using? standard `log` or `logrus` or another library? Also in the `TestNil()` method where is `s` variable definition? Are you sure `TestNil` does not contain any `*testing.T` argument?

Answer (score 1):

`LogNilValue` should have `MyMockedObject` as the method receiver, in order to mock the method. Something like this

```
func (m *MyMockedObject)LogNilValue(ctx string) {
    args := m.Called(ctx)
}
```

`CheckFunc` should look like this:

```
func CheckFunc(value *string, m *MyMockedObject) {
    ctx := "Some context string"

    if value == nil {
        m.LogNilValue(ctx) //void func that just logs the string
   }
}
```

And finally the `TestNil` method:

```
func TestNil() {
    m := new(MyMockedObject)

    m.Mock.On("LogNilValue", mock.Anything).Return(nil)

    CheckFunc(nil, m)

    m.AssertCalled(s.T(), "LogNilValue", mock.Anything)
}
```